# CSS - floating issue for a responsive design

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, position

Problem: http://i.snag.gy/TYvi4.jpg

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CadDC/7/

As you can see in the problem image above, I would like to position the image alongside the title but keeping the structure of the html for a responsive layout.

```
<div class="listingWrapper clearfix">
<div class="headlineText">FLOAT: RIGHT</div>
<div class="subText">FLOAT: RIGHT</div>
<div class="logo">FLOAT: LEFT (ALONGSIDE HEADLINE)</div>
<div class="introduction">FLOAT: RIGHT</div>
```

Comment: just as a side note: I am not keen to use position: fixed;

Comment: You have not explained how you want the design to look for a wide screen versus a smaller screen.  You are using a media query to alter the design at some screen width.  Is the posted image for the smaller screen or the larger screen?

Comment: Yes, the fiddle was incorrect. it should not include the media query in the CSS. And it is for the wide screen view

Comment: Is this problem solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/caprella/7kbVX/

I propose to add one more wrapper `.heading` for `.headlineText` and `.subText`. It will give us opportunity to move the whole header. But that `.heading` steel needs fixed width:(

Comment: I liked this idea because it was the closest to what i found that worked.

Answer (score 1):

Check the Js fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/CadDC/9/

```
<div class="listingWrapper clearfix">

    <div class="logo">
        <img class="listingImage" src="http://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/02/d0/d7/ed/hotel-du-vin-york.jpg" />
    </div>



    <div class="headlineText"><h2>Hotel name</h2></div>
    <div class="subText">Mars - 0.7 miles from Mars City Centre</div>
        <div class="introduction">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nost       
    </div>        
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cant you just:

```
.listingImage{
max-width: 190px;
float: left;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think this is your perfect answer http://jsfiddle.net/CadDC/14/ .
If you want it to be responsive you must give width and all in `%`.

Comment: I have not yet seen which is the correct answer.  am not currently at my PC.